# show products that belong to orders on admin pannel

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, associations

I am trying to show the name of each product that belongs to an order on my admin panel but I cant seem to get it.

here are my associations:

```
 OrderItem belongs_to :product
 OrderItem belongs_to :order
 Product has_many :order_items
 Order has_many :order_items
```

I have tried two different things:

```
<tbody>
    <% @orders.each do |order| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= order.id %></td>
         <td><%= order.order_items.product.name %></td>
         <td><%= order.total %></td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
```

This gets me this error:

```
undefined method `name' for #<Array:0x0000000535fbb0>
```

So then I try to loop through like this:

```
<tbody>
    <% @orders.each do |order| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= order.id %></td>
            <% order.order_items each do |order_item| %>
                <% order_item.products each do |product| %>
                    <td><%= product.name %></td>
                <% end %>
             <% end %>
         <td><%= order.total %></td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
```

And I get this error:

```
undefined local variable or method `each' for <Class:0x007fce540aa3f0>:0x007fce5417fed8>
```

Here is my controller code:

```
  def orders
      @orders = Order.all
      @order_items = OrderItem.all
      @products = Product.all
  end
```

I am not sure where I am going wrong any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: You almost got it in your second try. `order_item` belongs to a `Product`, so, you don't need your second loop, you can access your product with `order_item.product`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in either way you suggest: just keep an eye on your collections vs. items

### First Way:

This one puts all your items in a single `<td>`

```
<tbody>
  <% @orders.each do |order| %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= order.id %></td>
       <td><%= order.order_items.map{ |o| o.product.name }.join(', ') %></td>
       <td><%= order.total %></td>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
</tbody>
```

### Second Way:

Here, each `order_item` gets its own `<td>`

```
<tbody>
  <% @orders.each do |order| %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= order.id %></td>
          <% order.order_items each do |order_item| %>
              <td><%= order_item.product.name %></td>
           <% end %>
       <td><%= order.total %></td>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
</tbody>
```

You might consider adding some `has_many through` or `delegate` relationships in your models in the long term - it will make this kind of association a little tidier.

Comment: When I try the first way I now get :undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass

Comment: What happens when you try `OrderItem.all.map{ |o| o.product.name }.join(', ')` in the console? (My guess is that you will get the same error).

Comment: Reasoning: there's probably an `order_item` in the db with no associated `product`. You could check with `OrderItem.where(product: nil)` (also in the console).

Comment: Yeah you were right there were was a few orders without products once I got rid of those I was a able to get the first way working, thanks!